How to use FittedBox inside Wrap
I have children widgets in a Wrap widget.

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,

        child: SizedBox.square(
          // dimension: 100,
          dimension: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          // child: FittedBox(
          child: Container(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                FlutterLogo(size: 100),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Now the red square need to be smaller because of other dynamic widgets but I want to keep the items Wrapped layout the same, just downscale. I used FittedBox But it does not work, layout changes to inline, not wrapped anymore
class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,

              child: AspectRatio(
                // dimension: 100,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                child: FittedBox(
                // child: Container(
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                      FlutterLogo(size: 100),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text("Something else"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



use EXPANDED widget instead of FITTEDBOX widget.
